# custom pipe array empty

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I created this custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(items: any[], orderBy: string): any[] {
        if (items && items.length > 1) {
            console.log('items -> ', items);
        }
        console.log('return -> items -> ', items);
        return items;
     }
 }
```

I am using it in a component:

`<tr *ngFor="let item of items | orderBy:'title'" class="myclass">`

The table rows display correctly, but in the pipe the `items` array length is always zero.  The console statement for the return from the pipe shows an array populated with objects.  Why does the array appear to be empty?

Comment: Is items in your component getting data synchronously or asynchronously? It the latter, add 'async' pipe.

Comment: @wannadream no it isnt an observable so async pipe would not be a good idea.

Comment: Can you show component code? How you initialize items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add parenthesis as shown below.   This sends the item to the pipe and the result back to the ngFor loop.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of ( items | orderBy:'title')" class="myclass">
```

See: [Angular Offiical Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) Search for "ngfor" to see examples.